Should i need to remove UA code from the website if I've already migrated UA to GA4 and already add the GA4 tag in the website?
should i need to remove UA code from the website if I've already migrated UA to GA4 and already add the GA4 tag in the website?
Expected the solution of this, I want to know if I remove the UA tag from website will this effect on the traffic or do I need to extract any information from the UA?

Is there any reason why this question didn't work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929536/migrating-to-ga4-what-to-do-with-old-code?rq=2

Removing the UA tag will not affect your website traffic itself but will stop the data from being sent to the UA property. Your GA4 setup will continue to collect and report the traffic data.
Also it means you will stop collecting data in UA. If you need historical data or want to compare future data with historical trends in UA, make sure you have exported the necessary reports and data before removing the UA code.
Check if there are any other tools or systems dependent on UA data. If there are integrations or custom scripts that rely on UA, you might need to update or migrate them to GA4 as well.
If you are unsure or still need some UA data for comparison while fully transitioning to GA4, you can continue dual tagging (having both UA and GA4 tags) until you are confident that all necessary data and reports are available in GA4.
